# How to parse parameters from a string if they are split by a blank space

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, parsing

I am working on a project and currently I'm stuck.

I'm trying to parse from a string that's in this format

> `<string> <integer> <integer> <integer> <string>`

The string is given by the user, for example this is users input:

> Foo Bar 15 0 0 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

How would I get something like this?

> ['Foo Bar', 15, 0, 0, "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"]

Note: Strings can include integers

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex seems like a reasonable solution, but you can do it with one call to [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

When you include a capturing group (`(...)`) in the regex that you pass to `.split`, the captured text is included in the result array. This means you can split the text around the numbers but also capture the numbers with  a pattern like `/\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+/`.

For example:

```js
var input = "Foo Bar 15 0 0 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
var regex = /\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+/;
var result = input.split(regex);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @nstanard not sure what you mean by "seemed like homework". This format is for users input in one of my projects I tweaked it  before posting it used to be 
 <string> <integer> <string> <integer> <integer> but I didn't even notice I made 3 integers in middle of strings, still p.s.w.g gave an amazing answer and it's definitely cleaner than JS's string.split(). Thank you.

Comment: The answer that you were given IS javascript `.split()`.... I think you're confused. Good luck with your project (homework most likely)

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally use RegEx. Is the format of the string always the same?

If so.... I'd match the integer values:

`"Foo Bar 15 0 0 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".match(/(\d+\s)+/g)`

Then I would split using the resulting match.

```
let numbers = "Foo Bar 15 0 0 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".match(/(\d+\s)+/g)
["15 0 0 "]
let words = "Foo Bar 15 0 0 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".split(numbers[0].trim())
(2) ["Foo Bar ", " The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"]
```